# Why does IN not evaluate my regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Using Python 3.x, I am parsing through log files, and on most lines there are one of three key words (INFO, ERROR, or WARN).

I am defining the regular expression to see if a line contains either of these words as:

```
INFO|ERROR|WARN
```

I was certain that this was the correct way to go about this, but it does not seem to be working. Does anybody know what I am missing here?

I am checking to see if the regular expression is in the line simply by printing it:

```
Properties.py
    status = "INFO|ERROR|WARN"

Runner.py
    import properties as p
    import re
    line = "[time stamp] INFO [other information]"
    print(p.status in line)
    line = "[time stamp] ERROR [other information]"
    print(p.status in line)
```

Output:

```
False
False
```

It prints nothing but false.

Comment: And where is your call to the regex functions?

Comment: `_ in _`, when the arguments are strings, checks for substrings. Regular expressions aren't baked into Python.

Comment: Wow. I was not thinking clearly. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually call one or more functions in `re` (not use `in`) to use the regular expression engine:

```
print(bool(re.search(p.status, line)))
```

Comment: Thank you. Stupid mistake, was not thinking clearly.